# Fire onClick event to specific div

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

I have two cards and I am firing an `onClick()` event to create a dimmer on top of the card image if a user clicks on Like button (heart icon). I am trying to create the dimmer on the card image in which user clicked the heart icon.

I tried placing a condition :

```
if (e.target !== this)
    return;
```

But it did not work. In real webpage, I will have a long list of cards with no identifier where I can specify the image to be dimmed. Is it possible in this scenario?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frj8taua/2/)

Comment: In case of event capture or Bubble the Event.Target can be different from the element (`this`) on which the event is registered.

Answer (score 2):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frj8taua/4/)**.

You should use the current clicked jQuery object `$(this)` instead to target the related `.imglove` in the same `.card` :

```
$(this).closest('.card').find('.imglove').dimmer('show');
```

**NOTE :** The `.closest('.card')` is used to get the related `card` with clicked icon `loveit`.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.loveit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).closest('.card').find('.imglove').dimmer('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="ui card">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="right floated meta">14h</div>
    <img class="ui avatar image" src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/elliot.jpg"> Elliot
  </div>
  <div class="image imglove">
    <div class="ui dimmer">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="center">
          <h2 class="ui inverted header">Title</h2>
          <img class="ui avatar image" src="http://www.animatedimages.org/data/media/373/animated-heart-image-0455.gif">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar2/large/kristy.png">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span class="right floated">
      <i class="heart outline like icon loveit"></i>
      17 likes
    </span>
    <i class="comment icon"></i>
    3 comments
  </div>
  <div class="extra content">
    <div class="ui large transparent left icon input">
      <i class="heart outline icon"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add Comment...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ui card">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="right floated meta">14h</div>
    <img class="ui avatar image" src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/elliot.jpg"> Elliot
  </div>
  <div class="image imglove">
    <div class="ui dimmer">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="center">
          <h2 class="ui inverted header">Title</h2>
          <img class="ui avatar image" src="http://www.animatedimages.org/data/media/373/animated-heart-image-0455.gif">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar2/large/kristy.png">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span class="right floated">
      <i class="heart outline like icon loveit"></i>
      17 likes
    </span>
    <i class="comment icon"></i>
    3 comments
  </div>
  <div class="extra content">
    <div class="ui large transparent left icon input">
      <i class="heart outline icon"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add Comment...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So you're trying to limit your interaction to the currently selected image? Also, rather than reference a fiddle, post your working (or non-working) code here. Easier all around.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $(document).on('click', '.loveit', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).parents(".card").find('.imglove')
       .dimmer('show');
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui card">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="right floated meta">14h</div>
    <img class="ui avatar image" src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/elliot.jpg"> Elliot
  </div>
  <div class="image imglove">
    <div class="ui dimmer">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="center">
        <h2 class="ui inverted header">Title</h2>
        <img class="ui avatar image" src="http://www.animatedimages.org/data/media/373/animated-heart-image-0455.gif">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar2/large/kristy.png">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span class="right floated">
      <i class="heart outline like icon loveit"></i>
      17 likes
    </span>
    <i class="comment icon"></i>
    3 comments
  </div>
  <div class="extra content">
    <div class="ui large transparent left icon input">
      <i class="heart outline icon"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add Comment...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ui card">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="right floated meta">14h</div>
    <img class="ui avatar image" src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/elliot.jpg"> Elliot
  </div>
  <div class="image imglove">
    <div class="ui dimmer">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="center">
        <h2 class="ui inverted header">Title</h2>
        <img class="ui avatar image" src="http://www.animatedimages.org/data/media/373/animated-heart-image-0455.gif">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar2/large/kristy.png">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span class="right floated">
      <i class="heart outline like icon loveit"></i>
      17 likes
    </span>
    <i class="comment icon"></i>
    3 comments
  </div>
  <div class="extra content">
    <div class="ui large transparent left icon input">
      <i class="heart outline icon"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add Comment...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Target it `parent` with class `card` then `find` class `imglove` and add `dimmer` to it

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $(document).on('click', '.loveit', function(e) {
     $(this).parents('.card').find('.imglove').dimmer('show');
    });
 });
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/frj8taua/5/)